# How to build a search box similar to google - with rounded corners

Tags: html, css, textbox, searchbar

**I created a search box similar google search box. But the problem I run throught is, when i click the search box I get rectangle shaped box along with the rounded corner text box. How to get rid of it. Someone help me.**
[![This is how the search box looks like.][1]][1]
[![But, when i click on it, I get a rectangle box over it. How to get rid of this error?][2]][2]

**My Code:**

```css
.text_input input[type="text"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin: 250px 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 3px grey solid;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    
}
.text_input input:focus {
    background-color: grey;
  }
.text_input:hover {
    background-color: khaki;
    border-radius: 25px;
}


.search_box input[type="submit"] {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    font-style: normal;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-130%);
    margin: 320px 0;
    padding:10px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.lucky input[type="submit"]{
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    font-style: normal;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(20%);
    margin: 320px 0;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="https://google.com/search">
            <div class="text_input">
                <input type="text" name="q">
            </div>
            <div class="search_box">
                <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
            </div>
        </form>  
        <form action="https://www.google.com/doodles/">
            <div class="lucky">
                <input type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Help me to find a solution for this!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuchm.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0LTr.png

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm using Firefox and I don't see the box when I run the code snippet.

Comment: @Vlam scroll down after running the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your css.

```
.text_input input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: you're welcom! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use **focus** to the `input` in CSS

```
input:focus{
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. Your code worked well and helped me